# Creating deb file using Create deb file using debreate package builder

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, deb

I have created deb file using debreate package builder for LUbuntu 14.04. After installing deb file two options are there Reinstall and Uninstall.
It is working fine but when after reboot both the options are missing.

Anybody have any idea?